# excel stopping a cell form updating based on the time

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have a table that calculates the expected number of pieces to be made for each hour based on a hand full of criteria. as time passes a user is entering information into the actual pieces column. when the criteria (located elsewhere on the sheet) is changed the entire expected pieces column updates. the table look as follows:

[image]

I am trying to make it so that if the current time is after the time in the first column the expected pieces column will not update and will keep the previous value. for example if at 8:30 the expected pieces was 20, after it becomes 9:00 the 8:00 and 7:00 row will hold their expected pieces value while the rest of the column updates as the criteria changes.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this. is it possible to do on the front end or should I write some VBA code to control this?

How should I approach this problem? thank you!

Comment: how does 'expected pieces' currently update?

Comment: @tompreston there are a few drop down cells and based on what is in those cells, the expected pieces is calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to be coded in VBA.

As the values in your "drop down cells" will change, it is not possible for simple Excel formulas to store or access their previous states.

One could, howerver, imagine some quite ugly workaround with a different set of those "drop down cells" for every time slot.

**Some VBA suggestions:**

1) Disable Auto-Calculation

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
End Sub
```

Then only re-calculate those cells that fulfill your criteria:

```
Sub foo()
  If myCriterion Then
    Range("B3:D7").Calculate
  End If
End Sub
```

2) If your criterion is met, replace the formula with its current result

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 
  If myCriterion Then
    Range("B3").Value = Range("B3").Value
  End If        
End Sub
```

Note that if you want to use the same sheet on day2, you will have to restore the previous "formula" version of those cells.

*Please keep in mind user interaction. You should maybe  block some cells from user input to prevent undesired effects.*

Comment: is there not any code that could be used to simply freeze the expected pieces cells? as in hold the value there until the sheet is reset?

Comment: You could disable calculation, but that would affect the entire sheet. And I'm guessing then you'll need VBA anyways for recalculating the cells you actually want updating.

Comment: There is code for what you want; yes; but it is VBA code and not any Excel formula.

Comment: I am relatively comfortable writing VBA code so if what i am describing exists id like to do that. what kind of commands would be used to keep a cell from updating based on a criteria

Comment: @Vbasic4now i added some suggestions

Comment: is there a way to only disable auto calculation for a specific range of cells? there are claculations going on all over the document that i dont want to disable

Comment: afaik only on a per-worksheet-basis. Sheets("Sheet1").EnableCalculation = False. You could of course imagine a hidden sheet with disabled calculation, and your special cells referencing exactly that sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the following method is that the book has to be open; but you could use the application.OnTime method to cut and paste the values based on the time (copy paste values for one cell at a time on the hour every hour).  You'd have to have a formula in the cells to calculate them.  Does it sound like im barking up the right tree with this or am i missing the point?

Comment: i think you misunderstood. @Ulli Schmid is on the right track but i need to develop the idea a little more